# Vectors, Plotting a graph with a parametric equation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, graphing-functions, parametric

How do you plot the direction vector and how do you decide whether to take the negative of a vector or the positive when plotting it?

For the graph below, I got the normal vector as (-1, 2) but it is plotted as (1, -2). Also the direction vector here is (2, 1) but here it is plotted at (1,2)?

Graph:

[image: img1]

Equation:

[image: img2]

Equation in parametric form:

[image: img3]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Not sure I understand what you're asking, but: Either choice of sign for the normal vector is mathematically correct, and the direction vector is viewed as a _displacement_ from $P$, not an absolute position (displacement from the origin).

Comment: Thank you for your response, How do you go about deciding where to plot the direction vector then.

Comment: Why should it matter for the plot?